# Prevent Task.ContinueWith on exception

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am trying to prevent a task from continuing if the first part fails.

My code looks like that:

```
Task listener = Task.Factory.StartNew(openConnection).ContinueWith((t) => listenForNumber());

    void openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
           //stuff
        }
        catch
        {
          //morestuff
        }
    }

    void listenForNumber()
    {
       //even more stuff
    }
```

Now listenForNuber() should not be executed if openConnection() enters the catch block

I tried `ContinueWith((t) => listenForNumber(),TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);`

But no success, any help? :(

Thanks

Comment: Do you rethrow or swallow the exception inside that catch-block?

Answer (score 8):

`TaskContiuationOptions.NotOnFaulted` will obviously have no effect unless your method has faulted, i.e. an exception thrown during its execution was unhandled.

In your catch block, you should re-throw the exception (and preserve the stack trace) using the `throw;` statement after you've performed your work (some clean-up maybe) - otherwise the exception won't be thrown again, so your method will not be considered as 'faulted'.

Comment: Ok but if I rethrow the exception where is the best spot to swallow it (and how) so I don't get an AggregatedExeption or exception unhandled by user code? I don't need to handle it again as everything has already been done in the first catch block.

Comment: @Ekoms: as far as I know, the AggregateException is only thrown if you're accessing the task's `Result` property. That should be the one spot when you can swallow the exception, but first you should check whether it is really the exception you intend to swallow, and not just some unexpected exception.

Answer (score 2):

Create an extension method helper.

```
public static void PropagateExceptions(this Task task)
{
    if (task == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("task");
    if (!task.IsCompleted)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The task has not completed yet.");

    if (task.IsFaulted)
        task.Wait();
}
```

then call PropagateExceptions() extension method before executing any codes. PropagateExceptions() method will also rethrow if the task was cancelled.

```
t1.ContinueWith(t => { 
    t.PropagateExceptions();
    listenForNumber(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to throw the exception in your task method.  The TPL does not know the method has failed, unless it catches an exception.

You will still need to have a continuation method for the faulted case.  This could be a simple method that logs the exception.

If you don't have a continuation method for the exception, you will get unhandled exceptions in your application when your task method throws an exception.